# Fading text that turns into hyperlink?

Tags: html, css

My question may seem pretty weird but I wanna know if its possible to do somehting like this:
I want to add a text to my website that would fade away when someone points a cursor at it, then I would like a hyperlink to appear in the place of the faded text. I'd also like the reverse effect if the cursor is moved away from the text.
I know that you may not know what I mean so I made a quick (poor quality) vid that kinda shows what I mean

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK8dP5klI14&feature=youtu.be

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is possible through JS, but What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet since im just an amateur. I would be really thankful if you could help me out and tell me how should I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic example with jQuery.

```js
$(".hover-main").on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(".hover-text").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $(".hover-link").fadeIn("fast");
  });
});

$(".hover-main").on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(".hover-link").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $(".hover-text").fadeIn("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
    .hover-main{
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hover-link{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover-main">
      <div class="hover-text">
        Hover to see link
      </div>
      <div class="hover-link">
        <a href="http://google.com">Link to Google</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay umm I acutally tried to use that but I realised that its (as you obviously mentioned - dumb me) JQuery. Can you help me out a little bit more and tell me how should I "inject" this into html file? Sorry for troubling you but as I said, I'm an amateur ;(

Comment: Oh, I was not online for a while so could not reply. By the way, good that you found the solution.